# How to convert a typedef enum into using enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums, using

I'm trying to explore "using" in C++, and currently I would like to convert typedef into using.

For example,

```
typedef enum tag_EnumType : int {
    A,
    B,
    C,
} EnumType;
```

And I tried to convert it as following

```
using EnumType = enum tag_EnumType : int {
    A,
    B,
    C,
};
```

However, the compilation failed. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

The truth is, I'm working on a giant project. Some of typedef enum could be rewritten as using, but others couldn't. Does anyone know the reason? Is it related with namespace or sth?

Comment: You ask the reason why some can be rewritten, if you provide an example you may increase the chances for an answer

Comment: @MatG thx for advice, it seems like the enum in namespace defined by using could not be rewritten, so I wonder whether it's because some special organism of C++ using

Comment: I removed my answer since I didn't realize when answering that your code actually does work. As it is now, I would say the problem is non-reproducible without details.

Comment: "the compilation failed" How exactly? What error messages?

Comment: Cannot reproduce e.g. here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: Why do you want to use `typedef` or `using` at all? Specific reason?  Why don't you just write `enum EnumType : int { ... }`, which is the usual way in C++. Neither `typedef` nor `using` is needed.

Comment: Well, I've found my mistake, I didn't give the enum a type name, and used it directly as a new type. Say `using EnumType = enum : int` and `void testFunc(EnumType e)`, after the type name has been added, `using EnumType = enum EnumType : int`, everything well well.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef enum` is a C way of creating enums. If you want it the C++ way, you better write:

```cpp
enum EnumType : int {
    A,
    B,
    C,
};
```

In C++11 and above, scoped enums are also available, that way you prevent name collisions.

```cpp
 enum class EnumType : int {
    A,
    B,
    C,
};
```

`using` statements are for other typedefs, some examples:

```cpp
using IntVector = std::vector<int>;
using Iterator = IntVector::Iterator;
using FuncPtr = int(*)(char, double);
```